# What kind of rock is this being eaten by a rock-eating worm?

Tags: petrology, paleontology

The New York Times article [This Creature Eats Stone. Sand Comes Out the Other End.](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/06/18/science/shipworm-rocks-sand.html) describes the shipworm *Lithoredo abatanica*, an organism that appears to "eat solid rock".

It links to the item in Science [This rock-eating ‘worm’ could change the course of rivers](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2019/06/rock-eating-worm-could-change-course-rivers) which then links to the YouTube video [Snippet: Shipworms that eat rocks](https://youtu.be/K220SUWJ73w).

The video shows how easily this rock can be split apart.

The rock was taken from the bottom of the [Abatan River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abatan_River) on Bohol Island, in the Philippines.

**Question:** Is it possible from the images, descriptions, and video to say something about this rock? Is it a kind of sandstone? It looks fairly loosely held-together and porous.

---

Images from [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/06/18/science/shipworm-rocks-sand.html):

[image: Lithoredo abatanica, from inside a piece of rock]

**above:** Lithoredo abatanica, from inside a piece of rock. CreditM arvin A. Altamia and Reuben Shipway (click for full size)

**below:** Two large burrows in rock made by shipworms. Credit Marvin A. Altamia and Reuben Shipway (click for full size)

[image: Two large burrows in rock made by shipworms]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

thank you for your interest in the article. I'm the lead author on this paper (Shipway) and I happened to come across your post when looking through all the media stories on this animal.

To answer your question; yes, you're right, the rock is a calcareous sandstone. It was easy to split, partly because it is a naturally soft rock and partly because the shipworms had weakened the structure.

Hope that answered your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange and thank you for stopping by! It's fascinating stuff for sure. The paper [A rock-boring and rock-ingesting freshwater bivalve (shipworm) from the Philippines](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspb.2019.0434) mentions various limestones but doesn't say anything about sandstone. But I did just now notice that the NYTimes article does mention sandstone.